# JComboBox triggering null pointer even though it was not called on?

Tags: java

working on a school project. My program has an action listener for a jcombobox that once i hit submit, clears the box and hides it. Thats when it says null pointer, even though I'm not using it or clicking it after I clear it. Also, it only happens the first time I clear it.

```html
JComboBox sidComboBox = new JComboBox();
        sidComboBox.setFont(new Font("Lantinghei TC", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        sidComboBox.setBounds(139, 127, 222, 27);
        contentPane.add(sidComboBox);
        
         btnSubmit.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()  //adding action listener to the button component and creating a specific action performed method (override) for the button
                 {
                     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                     {        
                      
                      
                      if (btnSelect == 5)
                      {
                       sidComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                       sidComboBox.setVisible(false);
                       fnComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                       lnComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                       pnComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                       fnComboBox.setVisible(false);
                       lnComboBox.setVisible(false);
                       pnComboBox.setVisible(false);
                      }
                      
                      btnAdd.setEnabled(true);  
                      btnEdit.setEnabled(true);  
                      btnDelete.setEnabled(true);  
                      btnSearch.setEnabled(true);  
                      btnViewAll.setEnabled(true);    
                      
                      TAFirstName.setVisible(false);
                   TALastName.setVisible(false);
                   TAStudentID.setVisible(false);
                   TAPhoneNumber.setVisible(false);
                   lblFirstName.setVisible(false);
                   lblLastName.setVisible(false);
                   lblPhoneNumber.setVisible(false);
                   lblStudentId.setVisible(false);
                   btnSubmit.setVisible(false);
                   btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);
                   btnEditor.setVisible(false);
                         btnEditor.setEnabled(false);

                TAFirstName.setEditable(false);
                TALastName.setEditable(false);
                TAStudentID.setEditable(false);
                TAPhoneNumber.setEditable(false);
                
                TAFirstName.setText(null);
                      TALastName.setText(null);
                      TAStudentID.setText(null);
                      TAPhoneNumber.setText(null);
                      
                      sidComboBox.setVisible(false);
                      sidComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                      sidComboBox.removeAllItems();
                      fnComboBox.setVisible(false);
                      fnComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                      fnComboBox.removeAllItems();
                      lnComboBox.setVisible(false);
                      lnComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                      lnComboBox.removeAllItems();
                      pnComboBox.setVisible(false);
                      pnComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                      pnComboBox.removeAllItems();
                      
                btnSelect = 0;

                     }
                 }
         );  
   
   sidComboBox.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()  //adding action listener to the button component and creating a specific action performed method (override) for the button
                 {
                     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                     {      
                      int check = db.getNum() - 1;
                         if (check == -1) {
                          
                      }
                      
                      else {
                       int studentID = (int) sidComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                       int num = db.getNum();
                
                       for (int b1 = 0; b1 < num; b1++)
                       {
                        int nom = (db.studentList[b1].getStudentID());
                 
                        if (studentID == nom)
                        {
                         fnComboBox.setSelectedItem((db.studentList[b1]).getFirstName());
                         lnComboBox.setSelectedItem((db.studentList[b1]).getLastName());
                         pnComboBox.setSelectedItem((db.studentList[b1]).getPhoneNumber());
                         break;
                        }                            
                       }
                       
                       
                      }
                
                     }
                 }
         );
```

The error happens at this line specifically, not when I use it but when I hit the submit button.

```html
int studentID = (int) sidComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

I know its null, but I'm not calling on the box when its null. So why is it telling me its null??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you call `sidComboBox.removeAllItems();` in your submit-method. This changes the selection and therefore fires an `ActionEvent` as stated in the tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners).

Ways to circumvent this are presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258596/how-to-avoid-firing-actionlistener-event-of-jcombobox-when-an-item-is-get-added)

Comment: Thank you! What’s the easiest way to remove the action listener when I hit submit, then have it added back right after the submit function is done?

Comment: Actually don’t worry I figured it out. Thanks again!