# Is it possible to disable swing Actionlistener#actionPerformed() method with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258596/how-to-avoid-firing-actionlistener-event-of-jcombobox-when-an-item-is-get-added) exact problem with cyclic JComboBox updates.
I was thinking, maybe instead of using flags or a mouselistener, is there a way of creating a toggleable actionlistener yourself?

I wrote this so far:

```
public abstract class ToggledActionListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

    private volatile boolean enabled;

    protected ToggledActionListener(){
        enabled = true;
    }

    public synchronized void setEnabled(boolean flag){
        enabled = flag;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isEnabled(){
        return enabled;
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to find a way to cancel any actionPerformed() calls from objects that extend this class **IF** enabled is false.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an abstract class ToggledActionListener with only 1 abstract method like so:

```
public abstract class ToggledActionListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

    private boolean isEnabled;

    public ToggledActionListener(){
        isEnabled = true;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean flag){
        isEnabled = flag;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(){
        return  isEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(isEnabled){
            runIfAllowed(e);
        }
    }

    abstract void runIfAllowed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
someButton.addActionListener(someToggledActionListener);
```

or

```
someButton.addActionListener(new ToggledActionListener({
    @Override
    void runIfAllowed(ActionEvent e){
        //some code
    }
});
```

Use `someToggledActionLister.setEnabled(false)` to avoid cyclic event firing.

Comment: Personally, I'd use the decorator pattern - taking an `ActionListener` as constructor argument and calling that `actionPerformed` method if it is enabled.